# PolymerCLI - Error : Run the command "npm install -g polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz"

Tags: npm, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

Following the steps:

1. install polymer-cli

   Run the command : `npm install polymer-cli`
2. After install the bundled-debs :

   Run the command : `npm install -g bundle-deps`
3. After run the command :

   `bundle-deps`
4. Finally run the command :

   `npm pack`
5. Got the `polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz` file.
6. Now, run the npm install command,

`npm install -g polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz`

Result :

Get the error message :

````
```
C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN sinon-chai@2.14.0 requires a peer of chai@>=1.9.2 <5 but none was installed.
npm WARN sinon-chai@2.14.0 requires a peer of sinon@^1.4.0 || ^2.1.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@polymer\sinonjs-1e1235f0
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@polymer\sinonjs-1e1235f0' -> 'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\@polymer\sinonjs'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@polymer\sinonjs-1e1235f0' -> 'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\@polymer\sinonjs'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\nginx-1.13.7\html\polymer-cli\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```
````

Note:
****** - User Name

#### Versions & Environment

```
- Polymer CLI: 1.5.7
- node:  v.6.11.5
- Operating System: windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you installing polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz when you installed polymer-cli already in the first step? But not globally, you are missing -g switch in first step. What are you trying to achieve, which procedure do you follow? The issue could be related to permissions because you don't have rights to access that path, but you could try running console with administrator privileges. It is better to explain what exactly you want to setup so we can give you a better answer :)

Comment: Revolution88:   Thanks for response. Yes. Am sure to install in local not global. I checked already to run the command "npm install -g polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz" in administrator mode in terminal but not succeed. Finally, I want the result, Add custom options in "Polymer CLI" and get the option list from "Polymer init" and install polymer cli in globally without interent connection. I hope understand this.

Comment: Aha, I understand now :) Try adding --unsafe-perm add the end of your last command.

So it will be something like:
npm install -g polymer-cli-1.5.7.tgz --unsafe-perm

Comment: Revolution88: Thanks for your response. I will try this command. Cheers.